# Push JSON to an External WebSocket Error ESRI Geoevent

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, geoevent-processor

Has anyone successfully configured a `Push To An External Websocket` with ESRI geoevent?  I have an input a connector, service connector, and an output, however when I start the output I immediately get the error:

`Status: Error - Could not startup the WebSocket Transport. An initialization problem has occurred. Error: Connection refused: no further information.`

I increased the buffer and text bytes to `102400` in the settings  and used the default output settings:
`ws://localhost:80/ws` also tried ``wss://localhost:6180/ws2`

I am outputting a simulation stream to troubleshoot and I can output UDP so I know `GeoEvent` is working in some capacity.

I have tested this both on linux redhat 7.1 and windows 7 and the results are the same.  I can attempt any suggestions provided on either OS. And I am running ArcGIS Server 10.3.1 on local machines.

Comment: connection refused sounds like a firewall blocking the port - check the ports are open on windows and hardware firewall (through your IT) note: antivirus (ex avast) automatically blocks all ws events

Comment: Good suggestion..Firewall is off still did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geoevent OOB does not install with a connector capable of pushing data to a web socket.  The required connector can be found in the ESRI Geoevent Websocket tutorial located here http://www.arcgis.com/home/group.html?owner=GeoEventTeam&title=ArcGIS%20GeoEvent%20Gallery&content=all&start=1&q=tutorial&t=group&focus=group

It can be found in the folder \websocket\configurations and is imported with Site>Configuration Store>Import Configuration